# Did Yasir al-Ajlawni declare that it is lawful to rape any "non-Sunni Syrian woman"?

Tags: war, islam, sexual-abuse, syria

[This report](http://www.weaselzippers.us/147072-syrian-christian-girl-systematically-raped-by-jihadist-rebels/) claims:

> Fides sources point out that, through social networks, the fatwa was
>   widespread in Syria produced by Yasir al-Ajlawni—A Salafi sheikh of
>   Jordanian origin, resident in Damascus—who declared lawful, for
>   opponents of the regime of Bashar al-Assad, rape committed against
>   “any non-Sunni Syrian woman.” According to the fatwa, to capture and
>   rape Alawi or Christian women is not contrary to the precepts of
>   Islam.

Is it true or false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, "**Yasir** al-Ajlawni" certainly did not say that.

There is someone else called **Yasin** al-Ajlawni who isn't resident in Damascus who said something sort of similar and he claims his words are being misrepresented.

> The Human Events report lists “Salafi Sheikh Yasir al-‘Ajlawni” as the source of the rape fatwa. This is also the name given in the Arabic source for the story. **It turns out that there isn’t a Salafi Sheikh with that name. But there is a Salafi Sheikh Yasin al-‘Ajlawni, currently residing in Irdbid, Jordan, who does fit the description.** Those who are interested in a more accurate picture of things will find this early article, dated March 11, 2013 which correctly names the source. This article also includes comments from someone claiming to be “Yasin Ahmad Yasin al-‘Ajlawni” which are quite calm and sober, give backstory to what he said, and argue that his words are being misrepresented. There is a story here. It just isn’t the one they’re writing about.

http://musafurber.com/2013/04/04/the-medias-infatuation-with-gang-rape-fatwa/

> There is much wrong with this claim. First, the Jordanian Salafi would be “Yasin al-Ajlawni” not “Yasir al-Ajlawni.” Second, he is a resident of Irbid, Jordan, not Damascus, Syria. Third, Yasir al-Ajlawni denied making such a fatwa. Forth, the fatwa he referred to predates April 6 by many weeks.

https://freehalab.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/shaykh-musa-furber-exposes-the-rape-fatwa-hoaxes/

I can't go any deeper because of the language barrier.

Comment: @Oddthinking
 
the Electronic Intifada link appears to be about a very similar but older incident/claim about another person: Al-Arifi

Comment: !!! You are right. I made things worse with my last comment. Sorry. Deleted.